# What is the relationship between ghc-pkg and cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

With respect to how packages are created, installed and used in Haskell, what is the relationship between [ghc-pkg](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html) and [cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/)?

What are their roles - when would you use one, over the other, or use both?

Are they complementary tools, competitive tools, or simply tools that do different jobs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Graphically, the dependencies are:

```
Packages GHC can use
    | 
Are registered with "ghc-pkg register"
    |
And (almost always) built with Cabal
    |
With build dependencies resolved by cabal-install
    |
From Hackage.
```

Comment: Is it true then that any package registerable with ghc-pkg must have been built with Cabal?

Comment: No, that's not true. In the bad old days there was no Cabal, and we registered all our packages with make. 'make register' scripts abounded.

See `ghc-pkg register`

Answer (score 9):

[ghc-pkg](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-management) is a direct interface to GHC's package database. Cabal is a tool that provides a consistent distribution structure for packages and a way to specify metadata such as dependencies between packages, version numbers, and build information.

Using Cabal to install a package will register it with ghc for you (among other things), but that's the extent of the overlap, really.

Note that ghc-pkg also provides functionality that (as far as I know) Cabal doesn't, such as hiding installed packages.