# How are `ghc-pkg` and `cabal` programs related? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, relationship, ghc, cabal, role

As I know `cabal` is a program to manage installation of packages like FreeBSD's `pkg_add`.
But there is another tool called `ghc-pkg`. I don't know why there are two different programs. What's the role of each of them and how are they related?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706667/what-is-the-relationship-between-ghc-pkg-and-cabal

Comment: @Boris It's hard to understand why I couldn't find it with my title...

Comment: Yes, that's odd. They're very similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cabal is a building and packaging library for Haskell, kind of "Haskell autotools". It reads `.cabal` files and Haskell packages usually have a file `Setup.hs` which uses Cabal to build the package. Then there's also `cabal` command provided by the cabal-install package. It provides commands for running `Setup.hs` script and some package management functions, like installing packages directly from Hackage. You should read [this blogpost by Ivan Miljenovic](http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/) which explains the role of Cabal, cabal-install and Hackage quite well.

`ghc-pkg` is a lower-level tool for poking GHC's package database. Cabal is intended to work with every Haskell compiler, whereas ghc-pkg is obviously specific to GHC. You can't use ghc-pkg to build anything, you can just register packages you've built otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

cabal is just an interface layer to ghc-pkg with some added features.  It's only important to know ghc-pkg because uninstall functionality was not added to cabal, but can be done directly with ghc-pkg.

Comment: the ghc-pkg cannot uninstall. You probably meant unregister. And even after unregistering, I can still use the unregistered package just fine. As such, it is not an uninstall.